# How to redirect dynamic URLs to a static url?

Tags: url, dynamic, url-rewriting

I am running my site on **Apache Sever** with **Joomla CMS**. I need to re-write a dynamic url to keyword rich url.

I am new to url re-writing, I have been trying to solve this, but unable to succeed in this. In the website, i have used the keyword rich url for navigation, but i found this url in yahoo.. Don't know from were this url is coming...

I have the url as `www.example.com/keyword-rich-url.html`, but other dynamic url is also being indexed by yahoo..

The dynamic url is `www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=61&Itemid=92`

I want to re-write it to `www.example.com/keyword-rich-url.html` and redirect this dynamic url to the url which is used in the website itself, i.e `http://www.example.com/keyword-rich-url.html`

I tried this code

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=61&Itemid=92$ http://www.example.com/keyword-rich-url.html [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Before posting a question, do your own research and read Joomla documentation.

Check "Global configuration" section in Joomla Administration. There are options for SEO rewriting. Set them properly and make sure you rename *htaccess.txt* to *.htaccess* in the web root of your Joomla installation.

Comment: I have done that already, Global configuration is set to use mod_rewrite, search engine friendly urls is on, .htaccess file is already being used for other redirection.. My concern is to re-write this dynamic url to static, keyword rich... I already used keywords in the url while creating the internal navigation of links.. In the menu of home page, when you click on that page, you are being taken to www.example.com/keyword-rich-url.html.. But i saw a dynamic url for the same page in yahoo serp..